# PrimeFaces menubar image

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menubar

I have a problem consisting of not being able to put an icon to the left of the menubar and the menu items to the right, can anyone help me?

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar>

            <f:facet name="options" >
                <h:link outcome="index.xhmtl">
                    <p:graphicImage styleClass="a" name="img/logoGovernoTO.png"/>
                </h:link>
            </f:facet>


            <p:menuitem value="NOTÍCIA" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="FÓRUM" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="EXPLORE" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="SOBRE" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="CONTATO" url="#"/>

        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

I would have to stay like this
[image]

Comment: Look at the **client-side generated html** and try to use css to get the L&F you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
<p:graphicImage styleClass="a" name="img/logoGovernoTO.png" style="float: left" />
<p:menuitem value="NOTÍCIA" url="#" style="float: right" />
```

Comment: Yes, but it does not work .. I was able to resolve with the following changes in css
.ui-menubar .ui-menubar-options {
    float: left !important;
}
.ui-menuitem {
    float: right !important
}